# Manter cliente logado em http e https

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

Estou finalizando minha loja virtual desenvolvida em `codeigniter 3`  e banco de dados `mysql` está funcionando perfeitamente. Agora quero iniciar a configuração do certificado digital.

O meu problema é o seguinte: quando vou para o ambiente `https` logo no site tudo certo, mas quando volto para o `http` ele não mantém o cliente logado. Como posso resolver isso? Ou é assim mesmo e teria que fazer outra coisa?

Desde de já muito obrigado a todos os amigos.

Comment: Por curiosidade, de que forma você força o `SSL`? Nos controladores ou nos métodos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia amigo!

Adicionando isso no topo da "index" de cada página o HTTPS é automaticamente acionado, digamos, passa-se de HTTP para HTTPS

```html
<?
{
$new_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $new_url");
exit;
}


ForceHTTPS() //para chamar a função

?>
```

Qualquer dúvida estamos à disposição! Obs: Em meu website está funcional.

Comment: Bom dia @marlonLeandro com isso resolvo o problema de estar com uma sessão aberto no http tipo de login ou de carrinho de compra e será passada para o https.

Comment: Pode depender de sua plataforma de login, em meu website está funcional assim, o cliente loga em HTTPS e permanece em HTTPS por toda plataforma do usuário, seja: área do cliente, editar perfil, etc. para que assim ele não seja desconectado por passar de HTTPS para HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Armazene todos os dados dos usuário na `$_SESSION`. Ela estará disponível em qualquer instância, independentemente da criptografia.

Carregue a [Session Library no escopo](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class) ou com [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html#auto-loading-resources).

Eu já fiz um `helper` que recebia os dados do `FORM` depois de validados assim:

```
if( ! function_exists('session_set_userdata')){
    function session_set_userdata(){
        $ci = & get_instance();
        $controller = $ci->router->fetch_class();
        $method = $ci->router->fetch_method();
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        $data = [
            'session' => sha1(date('H:m:i')),
            'logged' => TRUE,
            'captcha' => $ci->input->post('captcha'),
            'method' => $method,
            'controller' => $controller,
            'email' => $ci->input->post('email'),
            'ip_address' => $ci->input->ip_address(),
            'user_agent' => $ci->input->user_agent()
        ];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $data;
    }
}
```